# Triangle printing letters in the wrong order, and unwanted characters

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, char

The purpose of this program is for the user to decide the length (rows) of a triangle, and also decide if it should be facing up or down. And the triangle is made of letters, so it is supposed to look like this:

```
How many rows would you like? (finish with -1): 4
Do you want the triangle to face up (1) or down (2)? 1

A
A B
A B C
A B C D

How many rows would you like? (finish with -1): 6
Do you want the triangle to face up (1) or down (2)? 2

A B C D E F
A B C D E
A B C D
A B C
A B
A
```

I have two problems when I try to get the triangle to print facing down, first the letters look like this (it should begin with an A)

```
F E D C B A
F E D C B
F E D C
F E D
F E
F
```

And the letters are followed by loads of different characters that I don't want. I've tried so many things and nothing seems to be working. I could really use some advice.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;

        while (a != -1) {
            System.out.println("How many rows would you like? (finish with -1):");
            a = scan.nextInt();
            if (a != -1) {
                b = a - 1;

                int j = 'A';
                char alphabet = (char) (j + 'A');


                System.out.println("Do you want the triangle to face up (1) or down (2)?");
                int c = scan.nextInt();

                if (c == 1) {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= b + 'A'; i++) {
                        for (j = 'A'; j <= i; j++)
                            System.out.print((char) j + " ");
                        System.out.println(alphabet);
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= b + 'A'; i++) {
                        for (j = b + 'A'; j >= i; j--)
                            System.out.print((char) j + " ");
                        System.out.println(alphabet);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    while (a != -1) {
        System.out.println("How many rows would you like? (finish with -1):");
        a = scan.nextInt();
        if (a != -1) {
            System.out.println("Do you want the triangle to face up (1) or down (2)?");
            int c = scan.nextInt();

            if (c == 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                        System.out.print((char) (j + 'A'));
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                    for (int j = a; j > i; j--) {
                        System.out.print((char) (a - j + 'A'));
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adopt a more modular solution given below.
It prints both triangles composed of 4 rows, one facing up and the other facing down.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  int a = 4;  // # of rows
  // Triangle facing up
  for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)   // i - How many letters in this row (also row No)
    printRow(i);
  System.out.println("--------");  // Separator
  // Triangle facing down - Start from the longest row, then decrease its length
  for (int i = a; i > 0; i--)
    printRow(i);
}

static void printRow(int length) {
  for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)   // j - char code shift
    System.out.printf("%c ", j + 'A');
  System.out.println();
}
```

This solution is more elegant, as the code to print a row is not repeated.

Note also a more natural way to express the length of consecutive rows: For the triangle facing down the loop decreases the row length.